# VS show suggestion for Generic Type Parameter

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense, type-parameter

My objective is try to ease my client when they are calling my codes. When writing a type parameter, the intellisense would no help. Is that anyway to show suggestion on client code when they tries to instantiate my class?

```
public interface IObjectA : IObject 
public interface IObjectB : IObject
public interface IObjectC : IObject

T GetObject<T>() where T : IObject;

public void Test() {
    var a = Gateway.GetObject<**ShowSuggestionHere**>()
}
```

Based on the sample above, i would like to show suggestion(IObjectA, IObjectB, IObjectC) to my client when they type until Gateway.GetObject<

Comment: If you use XML Comments on your methods, you will get Intellisense (including for Type parameters).  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/recommended-tags-for-documentation-comments

Comment: Hi, any update for this issue? Please check if Flydog57's reply help resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the XML comments suggestion @Flydog57. Says i added a few new interface IObjectD, IOjectE... then i have to go to the XML comments and modify the comment. Is that any way or extension available to help with this?

Comment: I'm not sure what your asking. You navigate to the definition of the Interface or base class (VS provides a "Go to declaration" command). Then add XML comments (type three slashes (`///`) on the line above the class definition and VS fills in a template for the class summary, and I think any type params. Then you type in the comments. What kind of extension are you thinking about?